# Comsuming WCF Service with Android

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio-2010, wcf

I'm trying to POST data to my WCF service from an Android Application, the service doesn't seems to be working, I think there is some problem with calling the WCF service. Can someone help or fix that bug! one thing more I didn't publish this service yet on IIS.

**Here is the code**

Iservice.cs

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(
        Method = "POST", 
        UriTemplate = "Cars",
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    void UpdateMyCar(myCar myCar);
}

[DataContract]
public class myCar 
{

    [DataMember(Name="Name")]
    public string Name 
    { 
        get; 
        set; 
    }

    [DataMember(Name="Model")]
    public string Model 
    { 
        get; 
        set; 
    }

    [DataMember(Name="Make")]
    public string Make 
    { 
        get;
        set; 
    }

}
```

Service1.svc

```
        public void UpdateMyCar(myCar myCar) {

        string strConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Database1"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);
        conn.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into TestingTable (Name,Make,Model) Values (@Name,@Make,@Model)", conn)) {

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", myCar.Name);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Make", myCar.Make);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Model", myCar.Model);

            int queryResult = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        } conn.Close();
    }
```

**Android Code**

```
public final static String LOGIN_SERVICE_URL = "http://10.0.2.2:8259/Service1.svc";
public EditText edt_carName, edt_carMake , edt_carModel, edt_display;
public Button btn_send;


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    xmlViews();
    RegisterListenerOnViews();

}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) 
    {
    case R.id.button1:

                 new sendPostData().execute();
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

}

private void xmlViews(){
    edt_carName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_car_name);
    edt_carMake = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_car_make);
    edt_carModel = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_car_model);
//  edt_display = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    btn_send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);


}

private void RegisterListenerOnViews(){
    btn_send.setOnClickListener(this);
}


private class sendPostData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    HttpPost request = new HttpPost( LOGIN_SERVICE_URL + "/Cars");
    request.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");            
    request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    JSONStringer getCarInfo;
    try {
        getCarInfo = new JSONStringer()
            .object()
                .key("myCar")
                    .object()
                        .key("Name").value(edt_carName.getText().toString())                                  
                        .key("Make").value(edt_carMake.getText().toString())
                        .key("Model").value(edt_carModel.getText().toString())
                    .endObject()
                .endObject();

    StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(getCarInfo.toString());

    request.setEntity(entity);

    // Send request to WCF service
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
    Log.d("WebInvoke", "Saving : " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    edt_display.setText("Success");
}
}

}
```

Comment: If you didn't publish the service on IIS, how are you hosting it?  Is the service host running? You have to host the service somehow (IIS, Windows Service or self-hosted) and it has to be running in order for it to work.

Comment: service is working and has been created. I just checked on VS-2010

Comment: You can access the service via a browser by entering `http://10.0.2.2:8259/Service1.svc`?  What error or behavior are you seeing when you try to access it from the Android app?

Comment: nothing happen just a sequential execution of the android app. and no entry in my WCF database